# MySQL Search with Join on Table and Meta Data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I'm trying to setup a JOIN, my LISTINGS table has META in the LISTING_META table, these listings are represented as cars.

When I search for a 1994 - 2014 car AND that is a certain BRAND I get no results, what I want to do is be able to return LISTING's that have META values matching the correct YEAR and BRAND but also future engine sizes , cc etc.

Im unaware of the best method but this is my current query:

```
 SELECT * FROM listing
 LEFT JOIN listing_meta AS l_meta ON l_meta.auction = listing.id
 WHERE status = '1' AND cat_id IN (24,25,26,27,28,29,30)
 AND (((l_meta.field = 'year' AND l_meta.value >= 1994) OR (l_meta.field = 'year' AND l_meta.value <= 2014)) AND (l_meta.field = 'brand' AND l_meta.value = '2'))
 AND price_start >= 0 AND price_start <= 999999
 AND time_end >= 1413347572 AND time_start <= 1413347572
 ORDER BY opt_highlight DESC, id DESC 
 LIMIT 0,9
```

I was thinking of doing EXISTS but that might be a bit heavy... is there something simple? Help is appreciated.

Comment: please give your source tables, some sample rows, desired output, actual output etc.

Comment: Sorry will do this next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to match multiple rows in the `listing_meta` table, you need to join with it multiple times.

```
SELECT *
FROM listing AS l
INNER JOIN listing_meta AS m1 ON m1.auction = l.id
INNER JOIN listing_meta AS m2 ON m2.auction = l.id
WHERE l1.field = 'year' AND l1.value BETWEEN 1994 AND 2014
AND l2.field = 'brand' AND l2.value = '2'
AND price_start BETWEEN 0 AND 999999
AND time_end BETWEEN 1413357572 AND 1413347572
ORDER BY opt_highlight DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 0, 9
```

You should also use `INNER JOIN` for this, not `LEFT JOIN`; use `LEFT JOIN` when you want the result to include rows that have no match.